# remove \ after pandas.to_json(orient='split')

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to send data to a chart using:

```
myjson = df.to_json(orient='split')
```

The problem I that when I see the information on myjson I see the information with many / characters:

```
"{\"date\": \"11-11-2018\", 
  \"descriptor\": \"111\", 
   \"data\": \"{\\\"columns\\\":[
        \\\"cddescriptor\\\",
        \\\"fechapublicacion\\\",
...
json.dumps(results)
```

Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Please try returning `json.loads(myjson)`.

Comment: I am using `json.dumps()`

Comment: thanks. `loads`did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myjson = df.to_json(orient='split')
json.loads(myjson)
```